# IIS, set dns name to IIS web site

Tags: iis, iis-7

How to set name to web site in IIS for browsing in LAN?

I've tried to change in hosts

```
192.168.198.83      mySite
```

but it doesn't work (required page is not opened)

I can remember IP addresses but other peoples do not want, so will be good to set friendly names.

Operating System Windows 7, IIS 7.

Comment: It would really help if you said what you expected and what you got (not just "it doesn't work". To improve this question please read: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to set the binding in IIS.

Go to IIS select the website then click on action Bindings.

The binding should look like:

Type: http / Host Name: MySite / Port: 80 / IP Address: 192.168.198.93

Comment: I set this params in IIS, then click on browse button, and get error in browser(mozilla) - The server at www.mysite.com is taking too long to respond.  and addressbar in address bar - http://www.mysite.com:17999/

Comment: Try setting the port to 80 (in IIS) like in my example